# Hot to add a specific string character in Query using PARAMETRISED SQL query construction method.?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is my query - `Select * from bigqueryproject1-279307.mycreatedataset1.newTabelwithAllDatatype where ST_INTERSECTS(rec11, ST_GEOGPOINT(-6, 6))`

I am trying to construct this Query using parametrised SQl but couldn't make it.
Can someone suggest how query will be formed for this?

Comment: what it is exactly that you want to achieve? you should provide more details on your use case so we can help.

Comment: As @MikhailBerlyant mentioned, you need to clarify your question further, but by reading your text, query parameter + EXECUTE IMMEDIATE might be something that you're looking for. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate